# how can I copy the files in path.txt to new folder with same folder structure?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

how can I copy the files in path.txt to new folder with same folder structure?
in my path.txt,there are some file paths. I want to copy these file to a folder which keeping the same folder structures. how to do the job using bat common?

```
includes/functions/extra_functions/functions_common.php
includes/functions/html_output.php
includes/templates/jy_default/part/list_content_products/list_content_products.php
includes/templates/jy_default/part/product_info_also_like/product_info_also_like.php
includes/templates/jy_default/part/product_info_main_image/product_info_main_image.php
subam/css/global.css
subam/includes/classes/class.jy_csv.php
subam/includes/main_page/sub_categories.php
subam/sass/bootstrap/_forms.scss
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your list does not have an absolute path you need to execute this batch file from the folder that contains your file.txt as well as the folders that are listed in file.txt

It's not tested: and your forward slashes should be backslashes but Windows will handle either.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
xcopy "%%a" "d:\target folder\%%~pa\"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont't need to read a list from a file. You could simply try this in command prompt:

`xcopy "full path to your folder" "full path destination folder" /e`

Below is what you get if you type `xcopy /?` in command prompt:

```
Copies files and directory trees.

XCOPY source [destination] [/A | /M] [/D[:date]] [/P] [/S [/E]] [/V] [/W]
                           [/C] [/I] [/Q] [/F] [/L] [/G] [/H] [/R] [/T] [/U]
                           [/K] [/N] [/O] [/X] [/Y] [/-Y] [/Z]
                           [/EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...]

  source       Specifies the file(s) to copy.
  destination  Specifies the location and/or name of new files.
  /A           Copies only files with the archive attribute set,
               doesn't change the attribute.
  /M           Copies only files with the archive attribute set,
               turns off the archive attribute.
  /D:m-d-y     Copies files changed on or after the specified date.
               If no date is given, copies only those files whose
               source time is newer than the destination time.
  /EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...
               Specifies a list of files containing strings.  Each string
               should be in a separate line in the files.  When any of the
               strings match any part of the absolute path of the file to be
               copied, that file will be excluded from being copied.  For
               example, specifying a string like \obj\ or .obj will exclude
               all files underneath the directory obj or all files with the
               .obj extension respectively.
  /P           Prompts you before creating each destination file.
  /S           Copies directories and subdirectories except empty ones.
  /E           Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.
               Same as /S /E. May be used to modify /T.
  /V           Verifies each new file.
  /W           Prompts you to press a key before copying.
  /C           Continues copying even if errors occur.
  /I           If destination does not exist and copying more than one file,
               assumes that destination must be a directory.
  /Q           Does not display file names while copying.
  /F           Displays full source and destination file names while copying.
  /L           Displays files that would be copied.
  /G           Allows the copying of encrypted files to destination that does
               not support encryption.
  /H           Copies hidden and system files also.
  /R           Overwrites read-only files.
  /T           Creates directory structure, but does not copy files. Does not
               include empty directories or subdirectories. /T /E includes
               empty directories and subdirectories.
  /U           Copies only files that already exist in destination.
  /K           Copies attributes. Normal Xcopy will reset read-only attributes.
  /N           Copies using the generated short names.
  /O           Copies file ownership and ACL information.
  /X           Copies file audit settings (implies /O).
  /Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
               existing destination file.
  /-Y          Causes prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
               existing destination file.
  /Z           Copies networked files in restartable mode.

The switch /Y may be preset in the COPYCMD environment variable.
This may be overridden with /-Y on the command line.
```

Comment: I need to read path from file, there are many paths , I can not type them all in cmd

Comment: This will copy all subfolders and files in the first path. /e does that.

Answer (score 1):

I see you tagged BATCH and CMD. Do you know any C#? The following .cs script should work and will give the option for a nice GUI.

In C# something like this would be very simple, you could use a while statement to loop the items in the list. While looping, you can concatenate the file/folder names to a location path of your choice and then copy the files to this location :

```
int counter = 0;
string line;
string concat_path = "C:\\my_new_folder\"
// Read the file
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\your_text_file.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
//copy the file, to the concat location, with the other folder names in place
//notice i have added "C:\" before the line, as it appears in your text doc you dont use full file paths, make sure you add the correct locaiton so that they can be found in sub folders
System.IO.File.Copy("C:\" + line, concat_path + line, true);
counter++;
}
//close the file open
file.Close();
```

Comment: sorry, I dont know how to use c. I only know a little batch commons